# why -W does not actually accept regexps for ignoring specific module?

Tags: python, command-line, suppress-warnings

During my tests I encountered 4 Deprecation warnings which are generated by a library my code use (and not by my code itself) so I decided to suppress the warning messages.

According to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters) the -W command line argument should accept a regexp as a third argument (ignore warning coming from specific module) but it seems is not true.

In fact, while this command could suppress all the warnings

```
python3 -m pytest . -v \
-Wignore::DeprecationWarning:aiohttp.connector \
-Wignore::DeprecationWarning:aiohttp.cookiejar \
-Wignore::DeprecationWarning:telepot.aio.api
```

this command, instead, (regexp one) does not suppress any warning:

```
python3 -m pytest . -v \
-Wignore::DeprecationWarning:aiohttp.* \
-Wignore::DeprecationWarning:telepot.*
```

(the same if I replace .* with [.*])

So it works if I write in detail the complete module package name, but not if I use a regexp for a global reference for the entire package (this case aiohttp and telepot)

Any idea why?

Tested on a virtualenv with python 3.7.1 built from source on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Did you try escaping the glob or use parentheses? Maybe it is interpreted by your shell before being passed on to the python interpreter. Try `"-Wignore::DeprecationWarning:aiohttp.*"` or `-Wignore::DeprecationWarning:aiohttp.\*`

Comment: It was a good idea, but unluckly it seems it did not work. I also tried ```-W"ignore::DeprecationWarning:aiohttp.*"``` and ```-Wignore::DeprecationWarning:aiohttp\.\*```. Thank for your suggestion :)